# Symfony flash message and data not refreshed after submission of a form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am using a modal form to update an address. Everything is working properly except that the flash message is not displayed or the view data updated after the form is submitted and therefore the page reloads. For the message to appear and the data to be updated, I have to manually refresh the page.

Here is the call of the modal form in my view :

```
...
          {{ include('_flashMessages.html.twig') }}
...
                    <a href="#profileAddress" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#profileAddress">Edit</a>
...
      <div id="profileAddress" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Profile address</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\user\\ProfileController::editAddress', { 'advert': advert.id, 'request': app.request })) }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
...
```

Here is the function called to render the form :

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/profile/show/{id}", name="user.profile.show")
 * 
 * @return Response
 */
public function show(User $user): Response
{

    $profile = $user->getProfile();

    return $this->render('user/profile/show.html.twig', array(
                                                                    'profile' => $profile,
                                                                    'bodyId' =>  'profileShow'
                                                               )
                        )
    ;

}
```

And finally, here is the action that I linked to my form to redirect to the initial view :

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'action': absolute_url(path('advert.vehicle.create', { 'id': advert.id })), 'attr': { 'id': 'profileAddressForm' } }) }}
...
```

Anyone have an idea of the cause of the flash message not being displayed and the address data not being updated in the initial view?

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT :

I solved 1 problem out of 2: by placing my modal div at the start of the template, the success flash message is now displayed correctly after submitting the form.

It remains now to understand why the data which has been correctly updated via the use of the said form is not refreshed in my view. Indeed, in this one, I have :

```
...
{% set profileAddress = advert.owner.user.profile.address.street %}
...
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    {{ form_row ( vehicleForm.situation.useProfileAddess, { 'id':'use_profil_address', 'label': "Use my profile address (" ~ profileAddress ~ ")" } ) }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <a href="#" data-focus=true data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#profileAddress">Edit</a>
                  </div> 
                </div>
...
```

The form updates the address data in the database, but these are not refreshed in the view when the page reloads after the form is submitted.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by "modal". Do you mean a "modal dialog"?
Is that "modal dialog" loaded via JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. Yes, it's a modal dialog with Bootstrap.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript part that loads the modal dialog?

Comment: I need the Bootstrap part to search for a possibility to redirect after the AJAX request made via Bootstrap.

Comment: Really thank you for your help. With Bootstrap modal, we don't need Javascript. : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ . It's the data attributes on the calling link that permit to showing the modal dialog. So, I don't use any Javascript code (Ajax) to show the form.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by

```
{% set profileAddress = advert.owner.user.profile.address %}
```

and

```
{{ form_row ( vehicleForm.situation.useProfileAddess, { 'id':'use_profil_address', 'label': "Use my profile address (" ~ profileAddress.street ~ ")" } ) }}
```